# Variable returns null at first row in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio* for building reports.

I have a variable which actually checks a column TODAY has null values of not. Expression of that value is

```
$F{TODAY} == null ? new BigDecimal(0.00) : $F{TODAY}
```

TODAY column has null values in my case for now.

The problem is first the expression above returns null for the first row and zero for the other rows. It should return 0 for every row since TODAY column is null

What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is leaving "initial value expression" part empty.
I added the same expression also to that field and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.  The older fix of use same expression for Initial Value does not work for me, because the first two rows now have same value.

I end up fix it by on iReport, changing the Variable:Property:Reset Type: to None.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and i fixed it by setting 'evaluation time' of the 'Text Field' showing the variable to 'Auto' instead of 'Now' in jasperSoft Studio